# Android Context Menu and List View Delete

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview, android-contextmenu

I am trying to delete an item in my listview through a context menu.  I have the context menu working and I can easily insert new items to the list view but I can not remove them.  I have two options edit and delete.

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item)
{
    super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    if(item.getTitle() == "Edit")
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if(item.getTitle() == "Delete")
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        myActivities.remove(item.getGroupId());
        populateListView();
    }
    return true;
}
```

for some reason, the item being deleted is always the first item!
myActivities is my dynamic array and all I do in populateListView is populate it.  I know populateListView works since if I add an item to myActivities then use the function, the new item will be added. Delete is not working though!

Note: I have also tried

```
    myActivities.remove(item.getItemId());
```

Comment: try delete item in your listview through adapter and then call notify method for adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me tell you the general approach for deleting item from `Listview`.

You have a list of data, which you pass to the adapter and through adapter display in `Listview` to the user.

So when you want to delete a particular item, first get the position of the item, delete it from the datalist. As the underlying data has been changed call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter which will make the `Listview` to refresh the child views.

Try following:

```
    if((item.getTitle()).equals("Delete")) // You are comparing Strings, don't use ==
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        removeItemFromList(itemPosition);             
    }

    // method to remove list item
    protected void removeItemFromList(int deletePosition) {

        your_datalist.remove(deletePosition);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                    
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot very clear. For people having trouble finding the position of the item use this!                          AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
int position = info.position;